# How do I purify the resulting compound after a nitro- to amine-group reduction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, purification, amines

I have an aromatic compound that I reduced with either $\ce{Fe + HCl}$ or $\ce{Sn + HCl}$.

How would you choose to go about extracting the compound?

I'm thinking to dry off all the $\ce{HCl}$, redissolve in water, and react out the iron salts to Iron Hydroxide, which can be filtered out.

Then dry out again, dissolve in something like acetone then filter out the sodium chloride?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Comment: What is the reaction you have just done and the compound you are trying to purify. This may help to determine how you purify it.

Comment: I downvoted. In this form we cannot possible help you, aside from very general statements. Please refer to the links @Martin kindly gave you to learn about how this Q&A site operates and what constitutes to a good question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to purify the amino compounds from the reaction mixture of reduction of nitro- to amine- group. Firstly, we will do  workup after completion of the reaction by extraction method with organic solvents  either with DCM or with ehtylacetate, then organic layer wlii be separated, and then dried with anhydrous sodium sulphate and the solvent will be evaporated under reduced pressure by applying rotary evaporator. Then after making slurry by adding little amount of silica gel we will pack slurry in Column-chromatography silica gel (100-200 mesh) by using eluent as Ethylacetate:Hexane (20% to 60%),  the amino- group compond will be purify. This is so because nitro- group is less polar compared to anino- group. So, nitro- compound will come first from column chromatograhy and amino- compound will come letter in pure form.